# Do NSOperation dependencies actually lead to memory leaks?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsoperation, bolts-framework

On the [github Bolts framework page (for ios)](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS#tasks), the list of advantages of BFTasks (essentially promises) includes the following statement about NSOperation dependencies:

"BFTasks release their dependencies. NSOperation strongly retains its dependencies, so if you have a queue of ordered operations and sequence them using dependencies, you have a leak, because every operation gets retained forever. BFTasks release their callbacks as soon as they are run, so everything cleans up after itself. This can reduce memory use, and simplify memory management."

Is this statement correct?

Comment: ps. it seems odd to me that [a fundamental design pattern recommended by apple](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=226) would generate such a memory leak

Answer (score 0):

NSOperationQueue releases all operations once their dependents and dependencies are complete.

So, for example, if I have an NSOperations called lastOperation that has a dependency of 200 other operations, then once the lastOperation is complete, all 201 NSOperations will be released.

If, however, there is no lastOperation that is dependent on the other 200 NSOperations, then each of the 200 NSOperations will be released as soon as they are finished.